# How to properly use Data.GetData() for parent classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm current trying to implement drag and drop for my listbox. I need to work with the elements that were dragged.

Each one of the dragged objects inherits Caliburn Micro's Screen and my BaseViewModel

For example

```
BaseViewModel : Screen

ListBoxItem1 DataContext = PersonViewModel : BaseViewModel
ListBoxItem2 DataContext = BusinessViewModel : BaseViewModel

private void ListBoxItem_DropEvent(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListBoxItem)
    {
        var source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(PersonViewModel)) as PersonViewModel ;
        var target = ((ListBoxItem)(sender)).DataContext as BusinessViewModel;

        int sourceIndex = Items.Items.IndexOf(source);
        int targetIndex = Items.Items.IndexOf(target);

        Move(source, sourceIndex, targetIndex);
    }
}
```

So the problem I have at the moment is that I don't want to specify PersonViewModel/BusinessViewModel I'm trying to get by typeof using inherited value hopefully BaseViewModel or Screen. May I get some tips or suggestions

I tried the solutions below but they returned me null.

```
var test = e.Data.GetData(typeof(BaseViewModel)) as BaseViewModel;
var test1 = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Screen)) as Screen;
```

Previous Mouse Event

```
private void PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = _dragStartPoint - point;
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
        (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
    {
        var lb = sender as ListBox;
        var lbi = FindVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource));
        if (lbi != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbi, lbi.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var test = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]) as BaseViewModel;
```